# How bash changes environmental variables on-the-fly?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

As we know, it's only possible to change the environmental variable set of a process in some time after the `fork()` system call and before `exec()`, e.g. manipulation like this is possible only from parent to child through the appropriate API.

However, when we use bash and it's `export` built-in, bash somehow changes the environmental variables of the current process (instance of the shell).

How this is done? Does it use some nasty hack?

Comment: `bash` *is* the current process; it's just changing its own memory space.

Comment: So it runs `exec()` over itself?

Comment: No, it just needs to modify its own `env` array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bash` is simply updating its in-memory variables. Despite the name, an environment variable is simply a shell variable whose value is copied into the environment of any child processes. When a shell instance starts, environment strings whose "name" (the part before the first `=`) are valid shell identifiers are used to create shell variables whose export attribute is set. When a new process is started, any shell variable with its export attribute set (whether from the environment or set later) is added to the environment of that process.

Comment: If they are internal shell variables with export attribute set on, why i can see the newly added environmental variables when `cat /proc/self/environ` using the current shell?

Comment: The environment is just part of the shell's memory space initialized by its parent.

Comment: @programings Because you're looking at the environment of `cat`, not the environment of the shell.